# Issue Matlab EPS figures

Tags: matlab, graphics, latex, eps

I have a problem when I create a EPS figure which I want to include in Latex. Somehow I am unable to place a caption above the figure created with Matlab. It gets overwritten by whitespace. I have created a minimum working example. The figure in matlab is created according the following code:

```
plot(1:10)
title('A line')
print('test','-depsc2')
```

And the corresponding latex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption is overwritten}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

No caption is visible in the output pdf. I am a dvi-ps-pdf chain.

It seems to be an issue with the bounding box values. If I add go to the draft mode of graphicx (\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} ) the caption appears.

Thanks for any help.

Best, Rob

Comment: Try to use `export_fig` from Matlabs FEX. Google it ;) generally solves all the problems related to printing figures in Matlab.

Comment: thank, ill give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Try the `clip` option in `includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, clip]{test.eps}
```

You may also want to include some vertical space between caption and figure:

```
\caption{Caption is overwritten}
\vspace{5mm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, clip]{test.eps}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the clip works well for the working example, however cutted the title in my particular problem. With \vspace i was able to solve it